# ADF: Fetch the remainder of rows in last page of RowSetIterator

Tags: java, performance, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a rowSetIterator with a total of 12 rows and a rangeSize of 5. I am accessing the rows like the following:

```
RowSetIterator rs = vo.getRowSetIterator();
int totalPages = rs.getEstimatedRangePageCount();
for(int pageIndex=0; pageIndex<totalPages; pageIndex++){
    rs.scrollToRangePage(pageIndex + 1);
    Row[] rows = rs.getAllRowsInRange();
    for(int rowIndex=0; rowIndex<rows.length; rowIndex++){
        Row row = rows[rowIndex];
        print(row);
    }
    System.out.println("going to next page");
}
```

But this code results in printing the rows as shown below:

```
1 2 3 4 5
going to next page
6 7 8 9 10
going to next page
8 9 10 11 12
going to next page
```

Is there a way to retrieve only the remainder of the rows present when scrolled to the last page i.e. access only the 11th and 12th row(from the above example).

The viewObject is an updatable one and of access mode SCROLLABLE.

The above case mentioned is just an example. In actual case, I am dealing with larger rangeSize and larger data. Hence, needed some help to tune my viewObject to be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A viewObject is a RowIterator, so you do not need to iterate through with your own looping like that.  By allowing the ADF framework to handle the range navigation, you should not encounter the same row twice.  The following should get you close:

```
vo.reset();//puts us at slot before first row
while(vo.hasNext())
{
  Row row = vo.next();//Automatically navigates rangesets when needed
  print(row);
}
```

If you are concerned with performance, please read: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/develop/adf-bc-view-object-tuning.htm

If you are iterating through all your rows, you may want to tune your view to have a larger range and fetch sizes (no more than 100 is typically recommended).

Finally, and more relevantly to your original question, you may want to ensure that "Fill Last Page of Rows when Paging through RowSet" option in the View tuning is NOT checked.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using vo.next() because it fires query because of ranging. The VO is a join of multiple tables and firing query every time takes a toll on the performance. But since I have found no other way yet, I will stick with this.